# I am receiving an infinite while loop when I run my code and enter the wrong input values. Does anyone know why, and how to fix it?

Tags: python

I receive an infinite while loop when I incorrectly enter the input for user_vendor or user_card. It works fine when I enter the correct values. card_check is set to the correct card value. The vendors I have listed are

```
def user_vendor(vendor):

 while True:

    if vendor == 'Visa' or vendor == 'MasterCard' or vendor == 'American Express' or vendor == 'Discover':

        print("\nValid vendor, thank you!")
        break


    else:
        print("\nPlease enter a valid vendor.")
        continue



def user_card(card, card_check):

 while True:

    if card == card_check:

        print("\nCard matches, thank you!")
        break

    else:
        print("\nCard does not match!")
        continue


def main():

 card_check = 5412753456789010

 vendor = input("\nPlease enter your Vendor for your card (Visa, MasterCard, American Express, Discover): ")
 user_vendor(vendor)
 card = int(input("\nPlease enter your card number: "))
 user_card(card,card_check)

 return;

main()
```

Comment: What are you expecting to happen exactly? You do not re-request input when the input fails. You simply take it back to the beginning of the loop with your 'continue' statement. You need to ask for input again if it doesn't match.

Comment: I was expecting it to ask to enter the input again. Do I just need to include the input statement again somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

The functions user_card and user_vendor are not updating the values of the card and vendor. Here is a better approach:

```
def user_vendor(vendor):

    if vendor == 'Visa' or vendor == 'MasterCard' or vendor == 'American Express' or vendor == 'Discover':
        return ("\nValid vendor, thank you!")
    else:
        return("\nPlease enter a valid vendor.")

def user_card(card, card_check):
    if card == card_check:
        return("\nCard matches, thank you!")
    else:
        return("\nCard does not match!")


def main():
    card_check = 5412753456789010
    while True:
        vendor = input("\nPlease enter your Vendor for your card (Visa, MasterCard, American Express, Discover): ")
        user_vendor_checkin = user_vendor(vendor)
        print(user_vendor_checkin)
        card = int(input("\nPlease enter your card number: "))
        user_card_checkin = user_card(card,card_check)
        print(user_card_checkin)


main()
```

Of course, you can optimize more but it will works fine

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following would be better fit. You have to re-request the input, otherwise you are simply repeating the check on the bad input.

```
def user_vendor(vendor):

 while True:

    if vendor == 'Visa' or vendor == 'MasterCard' or vendor == 'American Express' or vendor == 'Discover':

        print("\nValid vendor, thank you!")
        return True


    else:
        print("\nPlease enter a valid vendor.")
        return False



def user_card(card, card_check):

 while True:

    if card == card_check:

        print("\nCard matches, thank you!")
        return True

    else:
        print("\nCard does not match!")
        return False


def main():

 card_check = 5412753456789010
 vendor = ""
 card = 0
 while user_vendor(vendor) == False:
    vendor = input("\nPlease enter your Vendor for your card (Visa, MasterCard, American Express, Discover): ")
    user_vendor(vendor)
 while user_card(card,card_check) == False:
    card = int(input("\nPlease enter your card number: "))
    user_card(card,card_check)

 return;

main()
```